# problema ao criar um triangulo no after da div com css

Tags: css, html5

pessoal precisava criar um triangulo no meu `:after` da minha `div` porem esse shape teria que ser 100% de largura eu fiz um shape de triangulo porem ele está com largura fixa e isso não pode porque no mobile ele fica ruim e quando o site abre em telas maiores ele fica torto segue prints do que eu fiz com o código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Css que cria o triangulo:

```
#lp-pom-block-875{
    position: relative;
  }

  #lp-pom-block-875:after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -60px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 680px solid transparent;
    border-right: 680px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 60px solid #f9f0e9;
  }
```

OBS: Percebam que nas imagens que mostrei o triangulo não se ajusta pelo tamanho fixo e não sei como dar um tamanho de 100%;

Answer (score 1):

Não pode usar position absolute, senão perde a responsividade.
Esse width 100%, não funciona com position absolute.

Daria pra tentar usar media queries ou teria de mudar pra relative e ajustar na tela.

Comment: n da para usar media queries esse é o problema e se eu nao usar posição absoluta ele nao fica em cima do meu div

Comment: Tem certeza? se voce colocar relative, em todas divs, ai na div de baixo, voce coloca um estilo margin-top: -50px por exemplo, da pra usar valor negativo.